# Generated sql from LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Following code

```
ProductPricesDataContext db = new ProductPricesDataContext();

var products = from p in db.Products
               where p.ProductFields.Count > 3
               select new
                {
                    ProductIDD = p.ProductId,
                    ProductName = p.ProductName.Contains("hotel"),
                    NumbeOfProd = p.ProductFields.Count,
                    totalFields = p.ProductFields.Sum(o => o.FieldId + o.FieldId)
                };
```

Generated follwing sql

```
SELECT [t0].[ProductId] AS [ProductIDD], 

    (CASE 
        WHEN [t0].[ProductName] LIKE '%hotel%' THEN 1
        WHEN NOT ([t0].[ProductName] LIKE '%hotel%') THEN 0
        ELSE NULL
     END) AS [ProductName], 

    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[ProductField] AS [t2] WHERE [t2].[ProductId] = [t0].[ProductId] ) AS [NumbeOfProd], 
    ( SELECT SUM([t3].[FieldId] + [t3].[FieldId]) FROM [dbo].[ProductField] AS [t3] WHERE [t3].[ProductId] = [t0].[ProductId]) AS [totalFields]

FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [t0]
WHERE (( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[ProductField] AS [t1] WHERE [t1].[ProductId] = [t0].[ProductId] )) > 3
```

Why is this CASE statement for ProductName and because of this instead of ProductName i am just getting 0 in my result set. It should generate sql like following, (where ProductName like '%hotel%'

```
SELECT [t0].[ProductId] AS [ProductIDD], 
    [ProductName], 
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[ProductField] AS [t2] WHERE [t2].[ProductId] = [t0].[ProductId] ) AS [NumbeOfProd], 
    ( SELECT SUM([t3].[FieldId] + [t3].[FieldId]) FROM [dbo].[ProductField] AS [t3] WHERE [t3].[ProductId] = [t0].[ProductId]) AS [totalFields]

FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [t0]

WHERE (( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[ProductField] AS [t1] WHERE [t1].[ProductId] = [t0].[ProductId] )) > 3 
AND     t0.ProductName like '%hotel%'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is where you are having the problem:

```
ProductName = p.ProductName.Contains("hotel"),
```

`p.ProductName.Contains("hotel")` returns either `true` or `false`, or in SQL `1` or `0`.

Move the `Contains` to the `where` clause and in your select simply use:

```
ProductName = p.ProductName,
```

Alltogether:

ProductPricesDataContext db = new ProductPricesDataContext();

```
var products = from p in db.Products
           where p.ProductFields.Count > 3
           where p.ProductName.Contains("hotel")
           select new
            {
                ProductIDD = p.ProductId,
                ProductName = p.ProductName,
                NumbeOfProd = p.ProductFields.Count,
                totalFields = p.ProductFields.Sum(o => o.FieldId + o.FieldId)
            };
```

Comment: If I have to return ProductNames contains 'hotel' I need to add this in Where?
And this line is just returning true or false that returned ProductName contains 'hotel' in it or not?

Comment: @Muhammad Kashif Nadeem - the `Contains` function returns a boolean. If you want to limit the results to those where the product name contains `hotel`, then it belongs in the where clause. When selecting, the result set will only contain results matching the where clause.